# My seedling looks stressed and the leaves are wilting.

Tags: tree-care, plant-care, seedlings, wilt

Tonight I tried to give 4 hours of direct sunlight to my seedling, but after 4 hours of sunlight it looks so stressed the leaves went down. What should I do?

Comment: Was that the first exposure to direct sunlight for them?

Comment: How about a picture and telling us what species of seedling?

Comment: Hi! Is this your only seedling? If you have others, how are they doing? Also, have you recently changed your watering habit? The more information you can give us, the better! Just [edit] it right into the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't said what the seedling is, nor whether the sunlight was outdoors or in, but as a general rule, small seedlings should not be exposed to direct sunlight until they're grown on a bit and have established a good root system and several leaves. Once removed from the sun, if it doesn't recover on its own over time, there isn't much you can do,other than ensuring the soil didn't dry out too much in its time in the sun, and watering if it did so.

Comment: Are you only referring to seedlings started inside?

Comment: Primarily, but not necessarily